# Find and replace object inside object

Tags: javascript

I want to dinamically replace object inside parent object.

Object:

```
var obj = {
    address: { id: 2, type: { id: 1, label: 'Test1' } },
    id: 1,
    name: 'test'
}
```

Selector:

```
var selector = "address.type";
```

New inner object:

```
var type = { id:2, label: 'Test2' }
```

Now, what is the best way to replace "obj.address.type" with "type"?

My attemtp

```
tmp = selector.split('.'), obj1 = obj;
for(prop in tmp) {
    obj1 = obj1[tmp[prop]];
}
```

Comment: Why are you splitting on `,` although your "selector" uses `.` as a delimiter? You're also using the wrong iteration pattern for arrays.

Comment: I corrected it. But this is not the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selectors are given as strings, I presume.

```
function set(obj, selector, value) {
    selector = selector.split(".");
    selector.slice(0, -1).reduce(function(obj, s) {
        return obj[s]
    }, obj)[selector.pop()] = value;
}

set(obj, 'address.type.id', 'foobar');
```

If selectors are real pointers to objects, you can also replace them directly:

```
function replaceObject(obj, newObj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
        delete obj[k];
    });
    Object.keys(newObj).forEach(function(k) {
        obj[k] = newObj[k];
    });
}

replaceObject(obj.address.type, {'foo':'bar'});
```

Answer (score 1):

James Donnelly answered correctly but here is some quick code doing what I think you wanted to achieve... I apologise if I have missed your goal. I don't know what you want to do with the selector variable.

```
var objArray = [{
    address: { id: 2, type: { id: 1, label: 'Test1' } },
    id: 1,
    name: 'test'
},{
    address: { id: 4, type: { id: 3, label: 'Test2' } },
    id: 1,
    name: 'test'
},{
    address: { id: 6, type: { id: 5, label: 'Test3' } },
    id: 1,
    name: 'test'
}]

var lastId=6;for (var i=0,l=objArray.length;i<l; i++){objArray[i].type={id:++lastId, label:'Test'+lastId}};

JSON.stringify(objArray);
```